# Adding missing Input Formats after Minimal Install

Tags: input-formats

After a minimal install (v7.22) I've only got the 'plain text' input format and am missing the 'filtered HTML' and 'full HTML' formats. Is there a way to have just the missing formats installed or do I need to manually add them? If I have to manually fill in the details where can I get the information them as after searching I cannot find any details on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set them up exactly as they were in the default installation profile, you can just copy the code from `/profiles/standard/standard.install` and run it somewhere (e.g. at `/devel/php` with the Devel module installed):

```
// Add text formats.
$filtered_html_format = array(
  'format' => 'filtered_html',
  'name' => 'Filtered HTML',
  'weight' => 0,
  'filters' => array(
    // URL filter.
    'filter_url' => array(
      'weight' => 0,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
    // HTML filter.
    'filter_html' => array(
      'weight' => 1,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
    // Line break filter.
    'filter_autop' => array(
      'weight' => 2,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
    // HTML corrector filter.
    'filter_htmlcorrector' => array(
      'weight' => 10,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
  ),
);
$filtered_html_format = (object) $filtered_html_format;
filter_format_save($filtered_html_format);

$full_html_format = array(
  'format' => 'full_html',
  'name' => 'Full HTML',
  'weight' => 1,
  'filters' => array(
    // URL filter.
    'filter_url' => array(
      'weight' => 0,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
    // Line break filter.
    'filter_autop' => array(
      'weight' => 1,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
    // HTML corrector filter.
    'filter_htmlcorrector' => array(
      'weight' => 10,
      'status' => 1,
    ),
  ),
);
$full_html_format = (object) $full_html_format;
filter_format_save($full_html_format);
```